# Is a bounded bilinear map $a:V\times W\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous on $V\times W$ when $V\times W$ is equipped with the $\ell^2$-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be normed vector spaces and suppose $a:V\times W\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded bilinear map, ie $a$ is linear in each variable and there is a constant $C$ such that for all $v\in V$ and $w\in W$ we have
$$|a(v,w)|\leq C \|v\|_V \|w\|_W.$$

Is $a$ continuous if $V\times W$ is equipped with the norm $\|\cdot\|_{V\times W}=\sqrt{\|\cdot\|_V^2+\|\cdot\|_W^2}$?

At first this doesn't seem to be true since AM-GM only implies
$$\|v\|_V\|w\|_W \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\|v\|_V^2+\|w\|_W^2\right),$$
and a square root is missing. What should one do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should go back to the definition of continuity and check. Fix $(x_0,y_0)\in V\times W$ and compute $$ \vert a(x_0 +h, y_0+g) - a(x_0, y_0)\vert =\vert a(h,y_0) + a(x_0, g) + a(h,g)\vert \leq C \Vert h \Vert_V \Vert y_0\Vert_W + C \Vert x_0\Vert_V \Vert g\Vert_W + C\Vert h\Vert_V \Vert g\Vert_W \leq C (\Vert x_0\Vert_V + \Vert y_0\Vert_W + \Vert (h,g)\Vert_{V\times W}) \Vert (h,g)\Vert_{V\times W}.$$ Where we used that $$\Vert h\Vert_V, \Vert g\Vert_W \leq \sqrt{\Vert h\Vert_V^2+\Vert g\Vert_W^2} =\Vert (h,g)\Vert_{V\times W}.$$
Can you take it from here?